# Does Salesforce's REST API have a service accounts

Tags: rest, salesforce

I'm trying to interact with the Salesforce REST API for an organisation, and was wondering if it had any notion of Service Accounts or Application Owned Accounts. I can't find any mention of it in the documentation, but maybe they use different nomenclature.

I'd like to enable some form of domainwide delegation of authority, so users aren't faced with the pop up requesting access to their data. This is an internal app, only for this particular organisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are not service accounts.  There are 'Chatter' user licenses that are free but have reduced functionality:   http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/getstarted/?d=70130000000tRG7&internal=true#admin
FAQ:  http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/faq/